# password authentication failed for user "postgres" on mac

Tags: macos, postgresql, psql

I have problem creating new psql user because I cannot log in psql as "postgres", I have tried

```
1. sudo -u postgres psql

2. sudo -u postgres createuser img_site -P -s -e
```

and they are all ask for password of "postgres" which I don't know. I have tried to change unix password of user "postgres"(I know it's dangerous) and it still tells me: password authentication failed for user "postgres". I also have tried GUI pgAdmin but it's the same error.

I don't know if it's related: I have created a symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s /private/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/pgsql_socket/
```

in order to get rid of error

```
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: Add some context on how you installed postgresql in the first place. For example if you used `postgres.app` the postgres user doesn't even exist. Applying instructions out of context is a frequent problem in postgres on Mac OS since it's released in many different packagings. The symbolic link mentioned is also an instance of that class of issues.

Comment: @DanielVérité I used graphical installer.

Answer (score 3):

Check `pg_hba.conf`. it should have a line like this at the top (before all other entries):

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

This allows local Unix-domain socket access by `postgres` db user to all databases with no password required.

Now clear and redefine the password for `postgres` system user (which is automatically created during PostgreSQL installation):

```
sudo passwd -d postrges
sudo su postgres -c passed
```

The special thing about this user account is that postgres server allows it to connect to the database, no questions asked.

Now, to define an explicit password for `postgres` db user using which you can login via other means than local Unix-domain socket connection, run:

```
su postgres -c psql template1
psql> ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD '<password>';
```

You will be asked for the `postgres` system user account password before this command can be run. On successful completion, type `\q` to quit `psql` shell, and you are done with resetting the password for `postgres` db user.

Comment: I have added the line to pg_hba.conf but it doesn't help. It still ask me for password.

Comment: what if I dont find a user with named postgres in pg_hba.conf? Do I need to add this entry manually?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` doesn't want the password of the account you're switching to, it wants the password of the account you're switching *from*. It also requires that you be an admin (or otherwise listead in /etc/sudoers). `su`, on the other hand, requires the password for the account you're switching *to*.

Comment: I know this and I don't think this is the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to setup postgres for Ruby on Rails and I was getting the the password authentication failed for user error. Check if the server is actually running:

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status`

If you get

`pg_ctl: no server running`

Run

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`

Also you must include  localhost in psql.

`psql -U postgres -h localhost`

Comment: still asks for password.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

ALTER USER my_user WITH PASSWORD 'my_password';

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of different tricks on my Macbook. And here is the one which helped me.On the screen, right click PostgreSQL14 for 'properties', then in 'connection' tab **try to change** port number from 5432 to 5433(or vise versa) -> save. And try to open again, for password use "postgres". Should work

[image: screen]

Answer (score 0):

It got work's for me when I tried below approach in MAC m1 air

1. Go to "data" folder of Postgres's install directory
   /Library/PostgreSQL/16/data
2. select data folder(Initially it is locked state, don't allow you to open it)

3.On your Mac, select the item, then choose File > Get Info or press Command-I.

4.Click the arrow  next to Sharing & Permissions to expand the section.
Click the pop-up menu next to your username to see the permissions settings.

5.If you’re not logged in as an administrator, you may need to click the lock  to unlock it, then enter an administrator name and password (or use Touch ID or your Apple Watch).

6.Change the permissions to either Read & Write or “Read only”.

Then Try to login with credentials that you provided at the time of installation

### In my case:

host : localhost
port : 5432
name : postgres
pass : root