# connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: postgresql

Rails --API, when I run `rails db:reset` or try to do anything with my backend I get the following error:

`connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

PSQL previously worked, not sure what's changed.

I tried the fourth solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555352/password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-on-mac) page, but it doesn't work and tells me to check the server logs. My server logs are posted [here](https://gist.github.com/m-delc/a90b6e7aede763b0e5923d900aae9231).

I think I originally installed PSQL through Brew but I can't remember for sure. Either way, it was present when I ran `brew list`, so I uninstalled/reinstalled PSQL through Brew, but the problem persists.

Using DBeaver I tried changing both the connection port number and password but neither of these worked.

How can I get Postgresql back up and running?

Comment: Check postgres logs for the correct error message, sounds like an error in pg_hba file (show us this file).

Comment: Either rails used to send the password and now it doesn't, or PostgreSQL used to let you log in without a password and now it demands one.  Neither one of these things will randomly change for no reason, so you can be pretty sure someone changed something that caused this to happen.

Comment: Your server log shows a failed attempt to start, failed because a server is presumably already running on the same port.  Maybe some other db server was started (which prevents yours from starting yours) and now the other server is the one you are trying to connect to, but this other one demands a password.

Comment: @FrankNStein https://gist.github.com/m-delc/def58319113f03d687a6d5d00671e250 here is pg_hba in usr/local/var/postgres. I also have a folder usr/local/var/postgres-deletemewhenitsallgood which also has a pg_hba.conf. Is this normal? Seems incredibly strange.

Comment: @jjanes i see that in the server logs, just not sure how there could be another server as I rarely use this computer for production but the last time I did(a few weeks ago) psql worked

Comment: All is in trust, that means pg **don't** validate passwords. this is the current hba? In any case, search for postgres logs to know the exact error and recheck your connection settings to be sure we are checking the correct pg.

Comment: "I also have a folder usr/local/var/postgres-deletemewhenitsallgood"  Sounds like you need to start interrogating everyone else who has access to this machine.

Comment: @jjanes no one else has access to this machine, it might be something I did and don't remember